# cannot execute the function

Tags: python, class, function, odoo

Here is my class and methods.
I just wrote for get records and need to print them.but when run openerp in debug mode.its not worked & not go for that method also.& also need to clarify the fetching methods OpenERP 7

```
class namelistupdate(osv.osv):
def _mytest_query(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
    print ('here is demo sql query function result ')
    cr.execute("""SELECT module,(id*5000)as result FROM ir_model_data WHERE id=1""")
    res = cr.dictfetchall()
    print ('here is demo sql query function result ')
    print (res)

def _invoiced_rate(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context):
    self._mytest_query(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context)
    amount_untaxed = 1
    record_id = ids[0]
    res = {record_id: 0.0}
    if amount_untaxed == 0:
        res[record_id] = 100.0
    else:
        res[record_id] = 50.0
    return res

_name = "checkroll.namelist.update"
_description = "This table is for keeping Name list updates"
_columns = {        
    'date': fields.date("Date"),
    'val': fields.function(_invoiced_rate, method=True, type='float', string='Test', store=True),
}
```

namelistupdate()

error is below

```
Client Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 203, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)   File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1074, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(req, model, method, args, kwargs)   File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1066, in _call_kw
    return getattr(req.session.model(model), method)(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 43, in proxy
    result = self.proxy.execute_kw(self.session._db, self.session._uid, self.session._password, self.model, method, args, kw)   File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 31, in proxy_method
    result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)   File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 104, in send
    raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.ustr(e), formatted_info)


Server Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 90, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)   File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/netsvc.py", line 293, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)   File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 618, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)   File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 188, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})   File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 131, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 197, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)   File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 185, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)   File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 4479, in create
    self.pool.get(object)._store_set_values(cr, user, ids, fields2, context)   File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 4627, in _store_set_values
    result = self._columns[f].get(cr, self, ids, f, SUPERUSER_ID, context=context)   File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/fields.py", line 1131, in get
    result = self._fnct(obj, cr, uid, ids, name, self._arg, context)   File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/addons/checkroll/checkroll.py", line 55, in _invoiced_rate
    self._mytest_query(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context) TypeError: _mytest_query() takes exactly 7 arguments (8 given)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the *self* keyword in the paramater list.

Answer (score 1):

What you done in your code for calling a function from function is totally wrong?

In python to call a function, we specify the function name with the round brackets, which you not specified.

Second need to pass argument as number of argument in function.

So you code must be like this:

```
def _invoiced_rate(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context):
        self._mytest_query(cr, uid, ids, name, args, context)
        amount_untaxed = 1
        record_id = ids[0]
        res = {record_id: 0.0}
        if amount_untaxed == 0:
            res[record_id] = 100.0
        else:
            res[record_id] = 50.0
        return res
```

And after complete function return statement is needed otherwise return None be default.

You can refere how to define function in python: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

For openerp function you can get detail explanation here : http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_2.html Under "Function Fields" Tag.
Hope this help

Comment: now error comes as
AttributeError: 'namelistupdate' object has no attribute 'mytest_query'

Comment: you forgot a `_`: the function name is `_mytest_query`

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot _ in function name. thanks to Francesco Montesano for correcting me :)

Comment: now error is TypeError: _mytest_query() takes at most 7 arguments (8 given)

Comment: WTF!!! do not pass self argument in your function when call it from _invoiced_rate function